# How do I run Udemy app on any emulator?

Tags: android, emulation

I've tried on at least 8 different current android emulators to install and run the Udemy android app, but in all of them I get "This app is incompatible with your device," in PlayStore.

I have some courses in Udemy that I'd like to download with subtitles and currently the only way that I know of of doing that is by downloading them in android. I don't own a smartphone.

One thing I've found common in all the latest emulators is that they all emulate some sort of tablet and not a phone, as I can see in settings that all of them have "About Tablet" at the bottom.

I was hoping if someone could tell me of any emulator that's based on a phone (preferable a Samsung one) rather than a tablet. Or any other way I could change the emulator to show as a phone in PlayStore?

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted some time ago and I am not sure if you came right, but the only way I have managed to get it working is by installing Android in a VMWare Player virtual machine.

The steps I used are as follows:

1) Downloaded the Android ISO from http://www.android-x86.org/download (I downloaded the android-x86_64-7.1-rc2.iso)
2) Downloaded VMWare player from www.vmware.com
3) Followed instructions on here https://www.tactig.com/install-android-nougat-vmware/

It is possible to install on Virtual box from what I see, but I have never tried it. Instructions are here: https://www.avoiderrors.net/install-android-7-0-nougat-virtualbox/

From there I was able to install the latest version of Udemy, only message I got was that it was not optimized for the device.

Hope this helps.